# New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed' ErrorCode: VMAgentStatusCommunicationError

Tags: powershell, azure

So I am trying to create an Azure VM from a VHD (from a server running in Hyper-V) through Powershell. The creation process fails with the following error:

```
New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
ErrorCode: VMAgentStatusCommunicationError
ErrorMessage: VM 'Server' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage.
StartTime: 4/24/2017 12:26:57 PM
EndTime: 4/24/2017 12:52:39 PM
OperationID: 71739dce-4052-4114-82a4-dda1c3476711
Status: Failed
At line:10 char:7
+ $vm = New-AzureRmVM -VM $VMconfig -Location $location -ResourceGroupN ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

I've installed the Azure VM agent onto the virtual machine in Hyper-V.  I read the [following post](http://www.deployazure.com/compute/virtual-machines/azure-vm-agent-extensions-deep-dive-part-3/) about the error, and someone in the comments said you need to allow https to the storage account.  I've looked everywhere in the settings, and I'm not sure how to do this.  Am I missing something?  Could there be another reason it is failing?

In addition, the VM in azure that was created looks like it is running fine, but I can't RDP to it, even though I enabled remote desktop connections before uploading the vhd.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is my source code:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$vhdname = Read-Host "Please enter the new name of the VHD in Azure"
$vhdurl = "https://***********.blob.core.windows.net/******/$vhdname"
$resourcegroup = Read-Host "Please enter the Azure resource group for the VM"
$servername = Read-Host "Please enter name of Azure server to be created"
$virtualnetwork = Read-Host "Please enter the name of the Azure virtual network to be used"
$VMsize = Read-Host "Please enter the vm size in Azure (i.e. Basic_A0)"
$location = Read-Host "Please enter the region of the server (i.e. westus)"

$virtualnetworkinfo = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $virtualnetwork

$publicIp = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $servername -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
$networkInterface = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name "$servername`_VirtualNetworkInterface" -Location $location -SubnetId $virtualnetworkinfo.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $publicIp.Id

$VMconfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $servername -VMSize $VMsize
$VMconfig = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VMconfig -Name $servername -VhdUri $vhdurl -CreateOption Attach -Windows
$VMconfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VMconfig -Id $networkInterface.Id

$vm = New-AzureRmVM -VM $VMconfig -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup
```

Comment: Can you please add a snippit of the code you are using to create the VM.  Also, a screenshot of the "extensions" tab in the portal along with any error listed there (if different than above).

Comment: Do you open port 3389 on [Azure NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal)?

Comment: @Jesse Do you have NSG or firewall block 443(out bound)?

Comment: @CtrlDot I will edit the original bit with my code

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Yes I did open 3389 and no I have not blocked 443 outbound. Should I do that?

Comment: Also thanks for the comments!

Comment: Silly question, it is a windows VM right?

Comment: Also, was the machine syspreped?

Comment: Yep, it is a Windows VM, and yes, it was syspreped.

Comment: @JesseRussell No, you could not block port 443. I think you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image#set-windows-configurations-for-azure) to prepare your VHD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are not telling Azure what OS type you are trying to deploy.  It is a sysprepped machine, so there are some post tasks that need to be done to setup RDP, etc.

The command in specific I think you are missing is [Set-AzureRmVmOperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmoperatingsystem?view=azurermps-3.8.0)

EDIT: I see you are trying to attach a generalised VHD. You need to create the VHD from image, not attach. See [this article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
When I add the following line of code:
$VMconfig = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $VMconfig -Windows -ProvisionVMAgent -ComputerName $servername -EnableAutoUpdate
I get:
New-AzureRmVM : Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed.

Comment: I updated the answer.  If you have sysprepped you need to follow the generalized VHD deployment which uses the "fromImage" switch rather than the "attach"

Comment: No problem.  Do not forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped you.  Cheers